# How to run my entire arrayList of change objects though methods to get the change

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Okay so the program I'm working on needs to create an arrayList of change objects minimum of 1,000 and then compute the change that would be produced from that amount kind of like in a point of sale environment. I have everything working except I'm stumped on how to actually calculate the change. I have methods written in another class to do it, but I'm not sure how to pass the entire arrayList over to them in order to do so. If anyone could give me a hand with this it would be much appreciated.

Change class :

```
public class Change {

private double amount, remainingAmount;
private int occurences;


public Change() {
    super();
    this.amount = 17.87;
    this.remainingAmount = (int)(amount * 100);
}

public Change(double amount, double remainingAmount) {
    super();
    this.amount = amount;
    this.remainingAmount = remainingAmount;
}

public Change(float nextChange) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.remainingAmount = remainingAmount;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public double getRemainingAmount() {
    return remainingAmount;
}
public void incrementOccurence()  {
    occurences++;
}

public void setRemainingAmount(double remainingAmount) {
    this.remainingAmount = remainingAmount;
}
public double numberOfOneDollars() {
    int numberOfOneDollars = (int) (remainingAmount / 100);
    remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100;
    return numberOfOneDollars;
}

public double numberOfQuarters() {
    int numberOfQuarters = (int) (remainingAmount / 25);
    remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;
    return numberOfQuarters;
}
public double numberOfDimes() {
    int numberOfDimes = (int) (remainingAmount / 10);
    remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;
    return numberOfDimes;
}
public double numberOfNickels() {
    int numberOfNickels = (int) (remainingAmount / 5);
    remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 5;
    return numberOfNickels;
}
public int numberOfPennies() {
    int numberOfPennies = (int) remainingAmount;
    return numberOfPennies;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Change [amount=" + amount + ", remainingAmount="
            + remainingAmount + "]\n";
}
}
```

Change ArrayList Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChangeArrayList {
private ArrayList<Change> changeArray = new ArrayList<Change>();
private static int numOfChangeObjects = 1000;
private static String FILE_NAME = "changeData.dat";

public static void makeChangeData() {

    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try
    {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(FILE_NAME);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)  {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + FILE_NAME);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < numOfChangeObjects; count++) {
        //get random number between 0-1, move decimal right two places, typecast to float
        //to get rid of decimals, then divide by 10.0 to get decimal left one place
        //then add 3 to make sure numbers are >3 
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double changeData = (float)(Math.random() * 100)/10.0 + 3;
        double twoDecimal = Double.valueOf(df.format(changeData));
        outputStream.println(twoDecimal + " ");
    }
    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println("Those lines were written to " + FILE_NAME);
}

public void makeChangeArray(String fileName)  {

    changeArray = new ArrayList<Change>();

    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(FILE_NAME));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + 
                FILE_NAME);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    while (inputStream.hasNext())
    {
        //read in a change object from the file
        float nextChange = inputStream.nextFloat();

        //Stuck here. Can't figure out what to put in to make this work
        //everything else works except this. My change keeps coming out as 0
        changeArray.add(new Change(nextChange));
        //Stuck here. Can't figure out what to put in to make this work
        //everything else works except this. My change keeps coming out as 0
    }
    inputStream.close();
}

public void writeToFile()  {
    String fileName = "out.txt"; //The name could be read from 
    //the keyboard.
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try
    {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + 
                fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    outputStream.println(toString());

    outputStream.close( );
    System.out.println("Those lines were written to " + 
            fileName);
}

public String toString() {
    String s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < changeArray.size(); i++) {
        s += changeArray.get(i).toString(); }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ChangeArrayList.makeChangeData();

    ChangeArrayList tester = new ChangeArrayList();

    tester.makeChangeArray("changeData.dat");

    //Something should go here to calculate change
    //Not sure how to go about doing this

    tester.writeToFile();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

You can make **getter method** for `changeArray` in `ChangeArrayList`. And after calling `makeChangeArray()` method in main method, you can call getter method and pass that returned arraylist to required method as a parameter.

---

**Approach 2:** I wll prefer this approach.

Do not declare class level changeArray, instead declare it inside your `makeChangeArray()` method and change return type to `List` instead of `void` and return the prepared arraylist.